# What is the order of data returned with android audioRecord.read?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-audiorecord

When using audioRecord.read in android, will the first short/byte([0]) in the given array be the latest audio sample, or the oldest one?

Answer (score 0):

It is the oldest sample.

Audio data is ordered sequentially according to the time i.e., sample 0 recorded at 0th second comes first, sample 1 recorded at 1st second (not exactly 1 second, but explanation purpose used an interval of 1 second) comes second so on and so forth.